# adding two quotients where the single-variable is in the denominator of both, yet with diferent coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the equation I'm trying to solve for Physics:

$f(x) = \frac {K}{x^2} - \frac {K}{2(x-4)^2} = 0 $

Where $K$ is just some constant and $x$ is the single variable. I've got to find the x value where f(x) = 0.

It's probably just some simple algebra, but I'm stumped. Thank you!!

EDIT: Probably would help to get the symbols right ><

Comment: Start by multiplying through by the product of the denominators.

Comment: It is clear there are no (real) solutions unless $K=0$. Is there a typo?

Comment: gaaaah wow I feel dumb. It's been a while since I was in school haha thanks. But no, K is actually 8.988e9, and (crap I forgot) the first one has a coeficient of 1e-6 and the other 0.5e-6. My bad ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it helps to remember how to add fractions: by finding a common denominator. The common denominator of both of your fractions is $x^2 (x-4)^2$. If you multiply both terms by this, you recieve $$\frac{K(x-4)^2 +Kx^2}{x^2 (x-4)^2}.$$ Then you can solve by setting the numerator equal to zero.

Comment: Typo, an $x$ in the display should be $x^2$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks man, I completely forgot about this trick.